# C# Streamreader "The type or namespace name could not be found" error, but I've got the System.IO namespace

Tags: c#, using, streamreader

I'm brand new to C#, but I think I have the correct "using" statements here, so I presume the problem is somewhere in my class structure or syntax?  I'm getting the "The type or namespace name 'Textreader' could not be found" error.  Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Layouts.Test_control {

    public partial class Test_controlSublayout : System.Web.UI.UserControl 
    {
        private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

            Textreader tr = new StreamReader("date.txt");

            Console.WriteLine(tr.ReadLine());

            tr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C# is case sensitive FYI.  Also, better to wrap your `IDisposable`s in a `using` statement.  What happens if `ReadLine` throws?  You don't close your stream.

Comment: is it a typo in your example that you are referring to it as Textreader and not TextReader?

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio and the intellisense options are active, for C# it should be nearly auto-filling those keywords for you as you type them.  You can also try hitting ctrl+spacebar to see what you have scope to...

Comment: Nothing like a tutorial with a typo.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# is case sensitive so you probably want this instead:

```
TextReader tr = new StreamReader("date.txt");
```

Apart from that you've mentioned in your question that you would use the correct ["using" statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx), but obviously you're not disposing/closing the `StreamReader` at all. You're also reading only one line of the file.

```
// The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
using(var sr = new StreamReader("date.txt"))
{
    String line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use TextReader instead of Textreader. Note the uppercase R.

Answer (score 2):

Change Textreader to TextReader, It works

Answer (score 1):

C# is a case-sensitive language. Your "Textreader" object is misspelled. It should be "**TextReader**" See Below..

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Layouts.Test_control {

  public partial class Test_controlSublayout : System.Web.UI.UserControl 
    {
    private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

TextReader tr = new StreamReader("date.txt");

Console.WriteLine(tr.ReadLine());

tr.Close();
    }
  }
}
```